# Tabview scroll behavior

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, tabview, scrollable

I've a `Tabview` along with a list of `azlist scrollable bar`. When scrolling through the `azlist bar`, the `TabView` moves along easily trying to slide to another `Tab`. I want the `TabView` to be stay put during scrolling of the `azlist scrollable bar`. Is there a way to prevent this behavior for `TabView` ? I've tried declare a `CustomScrollPhysic` but it just didn't work the way I want it to be.

Below are attached gif & code for it.

[image]

**import this in pubspec**

```
alphabet_list_view: ^0.1.2
```

**home.dart**

```
import 'package:alphabet_list_view/alphabet_list_view.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 2,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: const TabBar(
            isScrollable: true,
            tabs: [
              Tab(text: 'TabOne'),
              Tab(text: 'TabTwo'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          child: TabBarView(
            physics: CustomScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              TabOne(),
              TabTwo(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**tabone.dart**

```
class TabOne extends StatelessWidget {
  TabOne({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<AlphabetListViewItemGroup> animals = [
    for (var animalLetter in animalsMap.entries)
      AlphabetListViewItemGroup(
        tag: animalLetter.key,
        children: animalLetter.value.map((animal) => Text(animal)).toList(),
      ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: AlphabetListView(
        items: animals,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**tabtwo.dart**

```
class TabTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  TabTwo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final List<AlphabetListViewItemGroup> animals = [
    for (var animalLetter in animalsMap.entries)
      AlphabetListViewItemGroup(
        tag: animalLetter.key,
        children: animalLetter.value.map((animal) => Text(animal)).toList(),
      ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlphabetListView(
      items: animals,
    );
  }
}
```

**custom_scroll_physics.dart**

```
class CustomScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  const CustomScrollPhysics({ScrollPhysics? parent}) : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  ScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor) =>
      CustomScrollPhysics(parent: buildParent(ancestor));

  @override
  Simulation? createBallisticSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    final tolerance = this.tolerance;
    if ((velocity.abs() < tolerance.velocity) ||
        (velocity > 0.0 && position.pixels >= position.maxScrollExtent) ||
        (velocity < 0.0 && position.pixels <= position.minScrollExtent)) {
      return null;
    }
    return ClampingScrollSimulation(
      position: position.pixels,
      velocity: velocity,
      friction: 0.5,
      tolerance: Tolerance.defaultTolerance,
    );
  }
}
```

**hardcoded maps of animals**

```
const Map<String, List<String>> animalsMap = {
  'A': [
    'Admiral, indian red',
  ],
  'B': [
    'Baboon, gelada',
    'Baboon, olive',
  ],
  'F': [
    'Fairy penguin',
    'Falcon, peregrine',
    'Frog (unidentified)',
  ],
  'G': [
    'Galah',
    'Galapagos albatross',
  ],
  'H': [
    'Hare, arctic',
    'Hartebeest, coke\'s',
  ],
  'I': [
    'Ibis, glossy',
    'Insect, stick',
  ],
  'J': [
    'Jacana, african',
    'Jackal, black-backed',
  ],
  'K': [
    'Kaffir cat',
    'Kafue flats lechwe',
    'Koala',
  ],
  'M': [
    'Macaque, pig-tailed',
    'Musk ox',
    'Mynah, indian',
  ],
  'N': [
    'Native cat',
    'Nighthawk, common',
  ],
  'P': [
    'Painted stork',
    'Porcupine, prehensile-tailed',
  ],
  'Q': [
    'Quoll, spotted-tailed',
  ],
  'T': [
    'Tailless tenrec',
    'Tapir, brazilian',
    'Tarantula, salmon pink bird eater',
  ],
  'U': [
    'Uinta ground squirrel',
  ],
  'V': [
    'Vicuna',
    'Vine snake (unidentified)',
  ],
  'W': [
    'Wagtail, african pied',
    'White-fronted capuchin',
    'Woylie',
  ],
  'Y': [
    'Yak',
  ],
  'Z': [
    'Zebra, plains',
    'Zorilla',
    'Zorro, common',
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a very similar page: two tabs both containing alphabet lists and the scrolling are working well.

I do not have a CustomScrollPhysics on my widgets, but use a TabController.

```
class _PeopleListScreenState extends State<PeopleListScreen> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;
  var tab = _Tab.user;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
    _tabController.addListener(() {
      if (_tabController.indexIsChanging || _tabController.index != _tabController.previousIndex) {
        var index = _tabController.index;
        // Tab Changed tapping on new tab
        setState(() => tab = _Tab.values[index]);
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            controller: tabController,
            tabs: [Tab(), Tab()],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              tabController: _tabController,
              children: [AlphabetList(), AlphabetList()],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Charles, may I know what package of AlphabetList you're using? I tried with TabController unfortunately it didn't work on my end. May I know also if the listener for tabController is needed? Because I thought it handles onTap and index changes on its own. Thanks

Comment: We are using one we slightly customized based on this
https://github.com/LiewJunTung/alphabet_list_scroll_view

Comment: Ok I got it, the package is using Listener instead of GestureDetector, I managed to solved it, thanks alot @Charles for the info that your alphabetList is working. :)